# ImagePullBackOff after Kubectl run

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes. I am using Minikube for Mac with VM hyperkit. I also have docker-desktop installed (in which I have tried both enable/disable Kubernetes).

docker pull is executed smoothly with no error.

but on

```
kubectl run kubernetes-jenkins --image=jenkins:latest --port=8080
```

(or any image, be it gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1) it fails with `ImagePullBackOff`

Trimming few parts from `kubectl cluster-info dump`:

> I1230 10:20:56.812648       1 serving.go:312] Generated self-signed
>   cert in-memory W1230 10:20:58.777494       1
>   configmap_cafile_content.go:102] unable to load initial CA bundle for:
>   "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file"
>   due to: configmap "extension-apiserver-authentication" not found W1230
>   10:20:58.778005       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:102] unable to
>   load initial CA bundle for:
>   "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
>   due to: configmap "extension-apiserver-authentication" not found W1230
>   10:20:58.849619       1 authorization.go:47] Authorization is disabled
>   W1230 10:20:58.850375       1 authentication.go:92] Authentication is
>   disabled
>
> "reason": "Failed",
>               "message": "Failed to pull image \"jenkins:latest\": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup
>   registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp
>   192.168.64.3:38558-\u003e192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused",
>               "source": {
>                   "component": "kubelet",
>                   "host": "minikube"
>               }

Why kubectl is unable to pull image from the repository?

Comment: Did you try to restart your Docker environment? `$ docker-machine restart default`

Answer (score 0):

In minikube your local docker registry docker image can't be found,so you have to set your docker env to use minikube registry for local image you build and pull

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

if that doesn't solve your problem, you have to start minikube by telling it's registry

```
minikube start --vm-driver="virtualbox" --insecure-registry=$(docker-machine ip registry):80
```

Comment: i am using a local image. Even if I execute --  kubectl run kubernetes-app --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1 --port=8080 ; i get same error.

Also, i tried minikube start as u said. I get this --
Docker machine "registry" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.

⚠️  VM may be unable to resolve external DNS records
⚠️  VM is unable to access k8s.gcr.io, you may need to configure a proxy or set --image-repository

Clueless :-(

Comment: eval $(minikube docker-env) did you do this??
and build the docker image after that again??

Comment: i did eval $(minikube docker-env) . Do i need to build image locally? I guess I can run through kubectl run directly like - kubectl run kubernetes-app --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1 --port=8080

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: what does your `docker ps` or `docker container ls` shows?

Comment: Try running a docker registry after $eval docker env,  docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2

Comment: docker stopped working.. I am unable to to pull anything from docker.

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.3:52401->192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused